# HTTPContext.Request Method Equivalent in .Net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, httpcontext

We used to write code in .Net Framework for `DataTable` filtering on server side.

This was the old code where `HttpContext.Request` was working fine. Now in .Net 6 how we can establish the same search and get `HttpContext` as well in any controller or model class from jquery.

This function is `static` and I am stuck in `HttpContext.Request` line where this is throwing exception "Httpcontext does not exist" even if we use `IHttpContextAccessor` here. How can we access that variable as that is defined in `Program.cs`.

```
 public static DataTable FilterTable(DataTable dt, ref int Fcount, JQPM p)
        {
            p.sColumnslist = p.sColumns.Split(',');
            string Fstring = ""; Int32 intVal = 0;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.sSearch))
            {
                string[] Arr = p.sSearch.Trim().Split(' ');
                for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Arr[i] != "")
                    {
                        Fstring = "0=1 ";
                        for (int j = 0; j < p.sColumnslist.Length; j++)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToBoolean(System.Web.HttpContext.Request["bSearchable_" + j]))
                            {
                                if (dt.Columns[p.sColumnslist[j]].DataType.Name == "String")
                                {
                                    Fstring += " or " + p.sColumnslist[j] + " LIKE '%" + Arr[i] + "%'";
                                }
                                else if (dt.Columns[p.sColumnslist[j]].DataType.Name == "DateTime")
                                {
                                    Fstring += " or " + p.sColumnslist[j] + "Format LIKE '%" + Arr[i] + "%'";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (Int32.TryParse(Arr[i], out intVal))
                                    {
                                        Fstring += " or " + p.sColumnslist[j] + " = " + intVal;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //Fstring += " PartyName LIKE '%" + Arr[i] + "%'";
                        //if (Int32.TryParse(Arr[i], out intVal))
                        //{
                        //    Fstring += " or SaleVoucherNo = " + intVal;
                        //}
                        //Fstring += " or SaleDateFormat LIKE '%" + Arr[i] + "%'";


                        //dt = GetDatatable(dt, Fstring, ref Fcount, p); Fstring = "";
                        dt = SearchDatatable(dt, Fstring, ref Fcount, p); Fstring = "";

                    }
                }
            }
            //else
            //{
            //dt = GetDatatable(dt, Fstring, ref Fcount, p);
            dt = GetDatatable(dt, ref Fcount, p);
            //}
            return dt;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpContext` has changed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext`; you will need to pass the instance of this from where `HttpContext` is available into this function.

`public static DataTable FilterTable(DataTable dt, ref int Fcount, JQPM p)`

becomes

`public static DataTable FilterTable(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext, DataTable dt, ref int Fcount, JQPM p)`

If you are retrieving `"bSearchable_" + j` from the QueryString and it will only contain that key once you can then use

```
httpContext.Request.Query["bSearchable_" + j].ToString();
```

where `httpContext` is the instance you pass in.

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-6.0#migrating-to-the-new-httpcontext

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thanks for your Answer passing HTTP context did the job for me